# JSP session.getAttribute() returning NULL value

Tags: java, jsp, session

I have create two JSP page one opens in IE and another opens in EDGE within same application.

How can i share data from One JSP page to another i have tried below but when i try to `getAttribute()` it return null.

**JSP A:**

```
<% HttpSession sess = request.getSession(true); 
        sess.setAttribute("firstName", 100); %>
```

**JSP B:**

```
var firstName = <%=session.getAttribute("firstName")%>
```

Comment: Normally sessions aren't shared between separate applications (nor should they be, almost ever). Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @Dave Newton   both JSP pages are running in same application.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question. If a user signs in in one browser *other* browsers don't automagically know they've signed in (and to do so has several downsides w/ few benefits).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JEE, there is a notion of scope that can help to store data for different purposes. There 3 scopes :

- Page scope: the data stored in the page request are only accessible by the page objects.
- Request scope: the data stored in the request scope are stored in an HttpRequest and are flushed once the request is handled. Other requests can not access what is stored in a request scope.
- Session scope: the session scope stores data that can be shared by all requests of that session, in this case, it is shared between all requests in the session.
- Application scope: there is one application scope per Servlet Context and data stored in the application can be accessed by all the sessions, requests, and pages related to that Servlet context.

You can find more information about scopes [here](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/jsp-scopes/).

To answer your question, you should use the `application scope` to share data between two web browsers.

To set an attribute directly into your JSP : you can use the pageContext Object with its method:

```
pageContext.setAttribute("attr","attr_value",PageContext.APPLICATION_SCOPE)
```

You can find more information about this [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jsp-pagecontext-implicit-objects/).

Comment: The OP's underlying issue is sharing sessions across browser apps, not scopes w/in the app.

Comment: I wanted to give him some more information as to why it doesn't and shouldn't work. I edited the answer to give the a more precise answer to how he could achieve that maneuver.

Comment: DaveNewton @BigZed thank you for helping me out, my problem is i have a object which needs to be share with other JSP page. and both JSP page are part of same application but opens in different browser. so i am trying to store the data in session object.  If any easy way to achieve without servlet. please let me know

Comment: I have edited the answer, check it out !

Answer (score 0):

The `session` is an implicit object in JSP and can be used directly. You can read about implicit objects in JSP in the [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/819-3669/bnaij/index.html).

```
<% session.setAttribute("firstName", "100"); %>
```

You should not create a new session with this code

```
HttpSession sess = request.getSession(true);
```

Comment: if i open JSP B from JSP A with window.open both will have same session ? and i can setAttribute in JSP A and getAttribute from JSP B ?

Comment: Yes, the session object is shared between requests.